# how to handle other module custom exception when it calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

In spring boot application there are two modules having their own custom exception classes. When one module call second's module function and if it throws any exception how to handle that exception in first module. I want to handle it in a standard way.

For example - Below is user module who is responsible to create manager and throws its **custom exception.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "manager", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity create(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody @Valid UserDto userDto) throws CustomException{
        User manager = userService.insertUser(userDto);
        return new ResponseEntity("Manager details has been added successfully", userDto);
    }
```

And there is another service module

```
public User insertUser(UserDto userDto) throws CustomException {
//some logic to create user here
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a code example for what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've updated description with code example, this might be be helpful for you.

Comment: Why don't you just surround it with a try-catch block? I don't see why that wouldn't work